# How to auto update formula in Excel when new row is inserted

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there any way to automatically update formulas referring to my data when I delete or add a row to my data?

Comment: Can you please be more specific. If I enter a number in cell A2, and put `2*A2` in cell A1 and insert a row in between then cell A1 will read `2*A3`, i.e. formulas are updated automatically. What else do you want?

Comment: @Howard : suppose you have 7 rows and you want the sum of column A, now first when you make the formula the range will go from A1 to A7 i.e. Sum(A1:A7) , now you add a new row , but the formula still is SUM(A1:A7), we want it to be Sum(A1:A8), that is the formula gets updated not the value of the formula. Regards

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at lists (XL 2003) or tables (XL 2007 & 2010).  These add the type of functionality you're talking about and may work for you.

Also, you could add a named range to your worksheet with a relative reference that refers to the cell directly above.  You could modify the example on this page under the heading "Using relative references."

Comment: named ranges are likely what should be used+1